# Is "Wer bist du von Beruf?" wrong

Tags: context

*A2 German, Sprechen Teil 1*, I got the card "Beruf" for *Fragen zur Person* and accidentally instead of "was bist du von Beruf" I asked this.

Comment: That sounds like: "Who are you of profession?". You can ask "what is your profession?" with "Was bist du von Beruf?" or "Was ist dein Beruf?"

Comment: The question might be suitable when we know that the person is a professional double and we want to ask who they are a double of. But that is still a stretch (and if the question is needed, they may not be so good at impersonating after all ;)

Comment: (+1) Grammatisch falsche Vermutungen berechtigen keinen Downvote. Ich sehe auch nicht, wieso diese Frage off-topic sein soll.

Answer (score 5):

*Wer bist du von Beruf* in German sounds like *Who is your profession?* in English, i.e. **wrong**.

You can ask:

- *Was ist dein Beruf?* or
- *Was bist du von Beruf?* (this more or less means: *Of what profession are you?*),

both meaning *What is your profession?*.

---

If you want to be cool (or annoying, depends), you say: *Was bimstu vong 1 beruf her?* ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The question word *Wer?* asks for an entity or kind, typical a name of a person or a named thing, but it may also be a job description as *die Köche* if the collective of all the cooks at that place is meant.

> **Wer** hat die Suppe versalzen? – Ein verliebter Koch.

In contrary, a *Beruf* is a profession as such, not a name of someone or something.

> **Was** ist der Beruf des Suppenversalzers? – „Verliebter Koch“.

Comment: Wenn man das Sprachniveau des Fragestellers berücksichtigt, wären weniger verspielte Beispiele vielleicht angemessener.

Comment: Ich versuche, die Beispiele interessant zu halten.

Answer (score 0):

It is wrong.
(If you don't try to convey the unlinkely scenario of someone being a different person by profession, for this, '**Wer** bist du **von** Beruf?' would be possible)

Difference between 'What is your profession?' (= Was...) and 'Who are you as a profession?' (= Wer...)